# Map Volume Serial Number to physical disk drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have few exactly the same drives in my desktop machine. I want to replace one of the drives which contains single volume (and it's the only disk that is used to create the volume). The problem is that I don't want to take out every disk one by one to see if the one removed is *the* one. Therefore I want to get serial number of the disk.

I'm able to get serial numbers of all disks with `wmic` and I'm able to get Volume Serial Number of the volume. How can I link them (preferably both using GUI and console)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible to map partitions (and thus drive letters) to the devices in WMI (which `wmic` queries). However it can require a little effort following the associations from one WMI object to others with [WQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): the "SQL Like" query language of WMI (see link for the documentation).

Using PowerShell (because I know it better, and it makes executing expressions much easier):

PSH also has a transcription ability, so with some editing and annotations:

```
PS [64] E:\ #35> gwmi WIN32_LogicalDisk

[...]

DeviceID     : F:
DriveType    : 3
ProviderName : 
FreeSpace    : 1660612608
Size         : 2147479552
VolumeName   : Messages

[...]
```

One instance of [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) exists per partition: usually a good starting point for anything to do with disks. But I want more details, including the meta-data to uniquely identify this instance so I can look for associations. So use `Format-List` (aliased to `fl`) to list all the properties:

```
PS [64] E:\ #37> gwmi -query 'select * from WIN32_LogicalDisk where DeviceId="F:"' | fl *


PSComputerName               : MyComputer
Status                       : 
Availability                 : 
DeviceID                     : F:
StatusInfo                   : 
__GENUS                      : 2
__CLASS                      : Win32_LogicalDisk
__SUPERCLASS                 : CIM_LogicalDisk
__DYNASTY                    : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH                    : Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="F:"
__PROPERTY_COUNT             : 40
__DERIVATION                 : {CIM_LogicalDisk, CIM_StorageExtent, CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement...}
__SERVER                     : MyComputer
__NAMESPACE                  : root\cimv2
__PATH                       : \\MyComputer\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="F:"
[...]
Caption                      : F:
Compressed                   : False
[...]
Description                  : Local Fixed Disk
DriveType                    : 3
[...]
FileSystem                   : NTFS
FreeSpace                    : 1660612608
[...]
MediaType                    : 12
Name                         : F:
[...]
VolumeName                   : Messages
VolumeSerialNumber           : 5A5189FB
[...]
```

And then to capture the `__RELPATH` (`__PATH` also works, but everything is local here, I don't need the computer name or WMI namespace: everything I'm doing with be in `root\cimv2`).

```
PS [64] E:\ #38> $DriveFPath = (gwmi -query 'select * from WIN32_LogicalDisk where DeviceId="F:"').__RELPATH
```

Now the clever bit: what other objects are linked to the drive's object:

```
PS [64] E:\ #39> gwmi -query "associators of {$DriveFPath}" | ft -auto __CLASS,__RELPATH

__CLASS              __RELPATH                                           
-------              ---------                                           
Win32_DiskPartition  Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #0"
Win32_Directory      Win32_Directory.Name="f:\\"                         
Win32_ComputerSystem Win32_ComputerSystem.Name="MyComputer"
```

This one looks interesting:

```
PS [64] E:\ #42> gwmi -query "associators of {$DriveFPath} where resultclass=Win32_diskpartition" | fl *

[...]
Name                        : Disk #0, Partition #0
__GENUS                     : 2
__CLASS                     : Win32_DiskPartition
__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_DiskPartition
__DYNASTY                   : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH                   : Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #0"
__PROPERTY_COUNT            : 34
__DERIVATION                : {CIM_DiskPartition, CIM_StorageExtent, CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement...}
__SERVER                    : MyComputer
__NAMESPACE                 : root\cimv2
__PATH                      : \\MyComputer\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #0"
[...]
Caption                     : Disk #0, Partition #0
[...]
Description                 : GPT: Basic Data
DeviceID                    : Disk #0, Partition #0
[...]
```

But does not itself contain what I want. So repeat the process:

```
PS [64] E:\ #43> $DiskPartitionPath = (gwmi -query "associators of {$DriveFPath} where resultclass=Win32_diskpartition").__RELPATH

PS [64] E:\ #47> gwmi -query "associators of {$DiskPartitionPath}" | ft -auto __CLASS,__RELPATH

__CLASS              __RELPATH                                       
-------              ---------                                       
Win32_ComputerSystem Win32_ComputerSystem.Name="MyComputer"              
Win32_DiskDrive      Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0"
Win32_LogicalDisk    Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="F:"
```

So it links back to the `Win32_LogicalDisk` where we started, but in this case that `Win32_DiskDrive` looks like it might be helpful (the value of the `__RELPATH` is a clue: I know that's the kind of naming Windows uses for its physical disks):

```
PS [64] E:\ #48> gwmi -query "associators of {$DiskPartitionPath} where resultclass=Win32_DiskDrive" | fl *


[...]
DeviceID                    : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
StatusInfo                  : 
Partitions                  : 2
BytesPerSector              : 512
ConfigManagerUserConfig     : False
DefaultBlockSize            : 
Index                       : 0
InstallDate                 : 
InterfaceType               : IDE
[...]
SectorsPerTrack             : 63
Size                        : 1500299297280
TotalCylinders              : 182401
TotalHeads                  : 255
TotalSectors                : 2930272065
TotalTracks                 : 46512255
TracksPerCylinder           : 255
__GENUS                     : 2
__CLASS                     : Win32_DiskDrive
__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_DiskDrive
__DYNASTY                   : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH                   : Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0"
__PROPERTY_COUNT            : 51
__DERIVATION                : {CIM_DiskDrive, CIM_MediaAccessDevice, CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement...}
__SERVER                    : MyComputer
__NAMESPACE                 : root\cimv2
__PATH                      : \\MyComputer\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0"
Availability                : 
Capabilities                : {3, 4}
CapabilityDescriptions      : {Random Access, Supports Writing}
Caption                     : ST31500341AS ATA Device
CompressionMethod           : 
CreationClassName           : Win32_DiskDrive
Description                 : Disk drive
[...]
Model                       : ST31500341AS ATA Device
Name                        : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
PNPDeviceID                 : IDE\DISKST31500341AS____________________________CC1H____\5&2CC8A95A&0&2.0.0
[...]
SerialNumber                : 2020202020202020202020205639325333323235
Signature                   : 
[...]
```

And there you have it. (I suspect the `SerialNumber`'s value is encoded—`20` could be the ASCII code for a space in hexadecimal, but checking that would need opening up my computer and getting the disk drive out: I'll leave that as an exercise :-)).